# Variables in string Jquery structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm receiving the error

> missing ; before statement

This is in reference to

> var westvars += ''+ (i+1) +'. '+
>   el.

Any idea what may be going wrong. I've tried removing the line/reconstructing the line ect. I just can't seem to figure out what part of the string is using an incorrect syntax.

```
var westvars = '<div class="clear">';
    westvars += '<div class="col-xs-2 teamname"><span>'+ (i+1) +'. '+ el.city +' '+ el.name +'</span>';
    westvars += '</div>';
    westvars += '<div class="col-xs-2 winsloss"><span>'+ el.wins +'-' +el.losses +'</span>';
    westvars += '</div>';
    westvars += '<div class="col-xs-2 gamesback">' + el.gback +';
    westvars += '</div>';
    westvars += '</div>';
```

Comment: your re-declaring var over and over.

Comment: you have both single and double quotes in that statement

Comment: And in your actual code, you have a `' ''` on the sixth line.

Comment: highly recommend to you read about basics and ideology of library before write down something, simply use append method or html and be carefull with quotes, for line-break use backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be changed this way:

```
var westvars = '<div class="clear">';
westvars += '<div class="col-xs-2 teamname"><span>'+(i+1)+'. '+ el.city +' '+ el.name +'</span>';
westvars += '</div>';
westvars += '<div class="col-xs-2 winsloss"><span>'+ el.wins +'-' +el.losses +'</span>';
westvars += '</div>';
westvars += '<div class="col-xs-2 gamesback">' + el.gback + ' ';
westvars += '</div>';
westvars += '</div>';
```

Comment: That seemed like it did the trick. Can you let me know which line you made a change to? I just went through it and can't spot the error/errors.  Thanks again @Axel

Comment: @Chris: every line ;-) in JS the term "var" defines a new variable. Thus `var x += 3;` must cause an error as `x`is not defined in the moment the right hand side gets resolved. And you actually had some quoting issues.